# html iframe trouble when you send value using get method

Tags: html, iframe, tags, get, frame

I've got an iframe tag in my html code. when I put the code like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The iframe is creating very well and generate a view of the site that I wanna get.

But if I put something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <body>

        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>

        </body>
        </html>
```

I get a white frame without content. 
I have tested it on a few sites and found that if you remove `?filename=tryhtml_iframe`
parameter the problem disapear.

The question is:

How could I use iframe with parameters that the site get by GET method?
or
Is there a different tag that I can use in HTML which don't get a that problem?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe is a true url where as http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp returns a 404

Comment: it is only a example. I wanna know in general why if the value is set by get method the iframe is not working well. If you put http://www.w3schools.com as url it is working well